# using mod_rewrite to change url path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to make a folder transparent in the URL like in the following example:
example.com/test/ 
changed to
example.com/

using mod_rewrite?

I like having folders for organization, but I want a nice clean url.

Comment: Changed how, using a redirect or an internal rewrite? Can you describe what is supposed to happen when a user enters the one URL, and the other?

Comment: Do you mean serving a file like `root_folder/test/page.html` as `example.com/page.html`?

Comment: @Pekka-internal rewrite would be best  
@Alberto-exactly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that with mod_rewrite putting something like this in the `.htaccess` file of your root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on

# the first condition is for avoiding an infinite loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /test/$1
```

This will redirect to `/test/` all the pages/files requested from `/`.

If you only want to redirect some files use more specific rule(s):

```
RewriteEngine on

# the condition is for avoiding an infinite loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/.*
# redirecting only images files and files that start with "doc"
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpg|png|gif))$  test/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(doc.*)$  test/$1 [L]
```

Or if you want to use different folders:

```
RewriteEngine on

# the condition is for avoiding an infinite loop
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/docs/.*
# redirecting only images files and files that start with "doc"
RewriteRule ^(.*\.(jpg|png|gif))$  images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(doc.*)$  docs/$1 [L]
```