# URL Rewrite - htacces

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite some urls on a website (rewrite, no redirection) but couldn't get it to work. So curious if someone can help me with this.

The following two pages using an url part I want to change.

> Archive Pages http://domain.nl/nproject-category/iphone
>
> Single Project Pages http://domain.nl/nproject/iphone-8

For the archive pages I want to change the url part (nproject-category):

> http://domain.nl/nproject-category/iphone to
>   http://domain.nl/reparatie-categorie/iphone

And the single project page url (nproject):

> http://domain.nl/nproject/iphone-8 to
>   http://domain.nl/reparatieoverzicht/iphone-8

Looking forward to some advice or solutions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you encountered this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170073/using-mod-rewrite-to-change-url-path . (assuming you have an Apache Web Server)

Comment: Yes, tried to follow it an some other tutorials but couldn't manage to get it to work:  
`RewriteRule ^nproject-category\/(.*) reparatie-categorie/$1`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single page accessible by multiple URLs, or different pages with similar content (for example, a page with both a mobile and a desktop version), Google sees these as duplicate versions of the same page. Google will choose one URL as the canonical version and crawl that, and all other URLs will be considered duplicate URLs and crawled less often.

[Google Canonical](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

Comment: Yes, I understand that. 
If I change the url structure I will tell Google the new url is the canonical url.